how to use speaker (msdos) in new computers?
I'm programming in assembly, and want to use the speaker, I can do that with out 43, al and out 61, al, this in Dosbox. But i've a notebook with DOS 6.22 in hd, all the program works well, but the speaker sound.
I tried to fix it, looking for some configuration in bios, but not found.
Whatever, is there some soundboard that i can buy, use in notebook, like old soundblaster?
Is anyway to setup the speaker in dos (real mode)?

Laptops often do not have the PC speaker wired up.  You'll need to write a driver for HDA or AC'97 to get audio.

If you're willing to have an attachment, how about a usb speaker or headphone?

@ErikEidt: USB audio devices are unlikely to provide the same IBM-PC compatible I/O ports to control the timer chip that drives the PC speaker with a square wave (IIRC) of a set frequency.  They're wanting to do retrocomputing running actual DOS directly on a laptop, I think, rather than running an emulator like DOSbox which produces PCM audio on any normal audio output.

in dos you can turn on the speaker by:
in al, 61h
or al, 00000011b
out 61h, al

and to close:
in al, 61h
and al, 11111100b
out 61h, al

now you can:
; send control word to change frequency
mov al, 0B6h
out 43h, al
; play frequency 131Hz
mov ax, 2394h ; 1193180 / 131 -> (hex)
out 42h, al ; Sending lower byte
mov al, ah
out 42h, al ; Sending upper byte


Yes, the OP said they're able to do this in DOSBox.  The question is why this isn't working on real hardware, on a laptop that's not ancient.  If the PC-speaker timer isn't hooked up to an actual piezo or speaker (or sound generator that mixes into the main speakers?), a program like this won't produce sound no matter what you do with software.
